# PhantomJs Could Not Find Element Like Chrome Driver Using Watir WebDriver

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I am having difficulties when using PhantomJs in my Watir webdriver.

Here is my code when selecting an element:

```
signInButton = driver.button text: 'Sign In'
signInButton.wait_until_present
signInButton.exists?
signInButton.click
```

It works fine when using Chrome but does not work when using PhantomJs.

This is how I start using Chrome:

```
@@driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-notifications --start-maximized]
@@driver.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 100 # seconds
```

This is how I start using PhantomJs:

```
args = %w{--ignore-ssl-errors=true}
@@driver = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, :args => args
@@driver.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 100 # seconds
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You should attempt to avoid using text as a locator when possible in favor of `browser.button` in this case, or `browser.button(type: 'submit')`. Additionally, you should not use `implicit_wait` with Watir. Watir by default does the waiting for you and implicit waits will just get in your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS is being deprecated in Watir & Selenium. Chromedriver has for a while been significantly faster, and now has implemented a Headless mode if you really need to have it be headless. Just add `--disable-gpu` and `--headless` to your array of switches.

Comment: THis is not a solution i guess